# Computer is "dying" - can't identify the source cause

Tags: windows-7, bsod, crash

The reason I chose to use the word "dying" in the title is the fact that my computer has many symptoms, which I couldn't find the source cause for them.
I'll write the information as detailed as I can, hoping it will help you help me.

**System Info**

- Operating System: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit SP1
- CPU: AMD Phenom II X4 955
- RAM: 4.00GB Dual-Channel DDR3
- Graphics card: 1024MB ATI AMD Radeon HD 5700 Series
- HDD: 1024MB ATI AMD Radeon HD 5700 Series

**Symptoms:**

1. Around one month ago - I received the BSOD a few times, (unfortunately didn't write the error codes - is there a way to restore them?). What I did is to delete a lot of unnecessary files I had on my HDD (especially in the windows drive, since it was pretty full). I managed my windows driver to around 35GB and the problems stopped.
2. A few days ago the problem returned, mixed with some other problems. These are the main problems I encountered in the last few days:

   1. I have had the BSOD again (and how great - I didn't write the error code again, not a smart move by myself..).
   2. The computer sometime crash without any blue screen or error coming up, forcing me to restart the computer.
   3. Many times in the past few days the computer didn't boot well. It was either stuck on the motherboard start screen, or even didn't get there and only gave out beeps (in sound) every 3 seconds or so. Sometimes it got stuck on the loading screen.
   4. The problem of crashing/getting stuck occurred during video gameplay more often. The screen just freezes and the sound get stuck (infinite loop of about 0.1 sec of the last played audio in the game). Only restarting the computer helps it (and then I usually encounter boot problems).

**What I have tried/checked**

1. Viruses : checked my computer with both Avast and Malwarebytes and haven't found any viruses.
2. Tests: I have ran multiple stress tests to the RAM,CPU and the GPU, all came out fine.
3. Temperatures: temp is ok across all components, normally around 45-50 Celsius while stressing the GPU gives out around 90C which is also fine.

I hope I gave a detailed explanation of my PC's problems, which will help you guide me throughout further tests I should do and hopefully a solution. I will be also sure to write the error code of the next BSOD, and will update here if it will happen again.

Comment: Describe the beeps: how many, how far apart, etc.

Comment: @Xavierjazz they are around 3 seconds apart, and I don't know how many since eventually I just turn off the computer and "let it rest" for a bit before turning it on again. It continues until I turn off the computer, so at least 4-5 times.

Comment: It is quite possibly a code that will point to where the problem is. Count them and time the intervals between them. Do they repeat?

Comment: @Xavierjazz didn't think that the beeping are code for an error, I thought that they were simply some malfunction in one of the hardware components. I will definitely analyze them the next time it happens. Meanwhile (while I wait for another occurrence of the lovely beeps), can you help me with other ideas/tests I can do? Many thanks!

Comment: To test if it's a hardware failure (read as "expensive") or just OS/software, boot from a Linux version running on a USB flash drive (e.g. Ubuntu Live). If it runs perfectly from flash, then the issue is either Windows or the HDD. Scan the HDD for hard and soft errors (from Windows or Ultimate Boot CD).